# How to Push Calculated Value to Multidimensional JSON Object and Sort Parent and Child Objects Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, multidimensional-array, vuejs2

I have a multidimensional JSON feed of individual events each with many different dates and locations. Each date within said event includes latitude and longitude which I calculate distance using HTML5 geolocation. I want to push that distance into the child object and sort not only by distance, but the also sort events by the distance of each date kept grouped.

I have tried sorting inline, using v-for but I have since learned this does not work in vue2 and does not solve the problem of sorting parent events. I have included an example of what I'm working on below:

HTML:

```
<div id="string">
  <p><strong>Current Geolocation:</strong> {{lat}}:{{lon}}</p>
  <ol v-for="seminar in seminars">
    <li>
      {{seminar.title}}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="event in seminar.events">
          {{event.webtitle}} <strong>{{calcDist(lat,lon,event.location.lat,event.location.lon,N)}} Miles Away</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Methods:

```
methods: {
    getLocation: function () {      
      if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition, this.errorCallback);
      } else {
        this.error = "Geolocation is not supported.";
      }
    },
    showPosition: function (position) { 
      this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.lon = position.coords.longitude;
      this.googleQuery(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    },
    calcDist: function (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
      if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
        var theta = lon1-lon2;
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        if (dist > 1) {
          dist = 1;
        }
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return Math.round(dist);
      }
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.getLocation();
  }
```

[JSFiddle Example with Data Structure and Current Progress](https://jsfiddle.net/8njwcL01/31/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use case for computed properties. I don't quite understand some of the details of the question (e.g. on what basis are seminars to be sorted?) but the general approach below should work. It uses multiple computed properties for clarity, but they could be combined if desired.

```
computed: {
    seminarsWithDistance() {
        return this.seminars.forEach(seminar => {
            seminar.events.forEach(event => {
                event.distance = calcDist(/*...*/);
            });
        });
    },
    seminarsWithSortedEvents() {
        return this.seminarsWithDistance.forEach(seminar => {
            seminar.events.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance);
        });
    },
    sortedSeminars() {
        return this.seminarsWithSortedEvents.sort((a, b) => {
            /* some compare function for two seminars a and b */
        });
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of using the computed property in the template

```
<ol v-for="seminar in sortedSeminars">
```